# Can I use setTimeout() on JavaScript as a parallel processed function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know JS is single threaded. But I have a function which takes time for the calculation. I would like it to work paralleled, so this function would not freeze next statement. Calculation inside of function will take approximately 1-2 seconds.

1. I used to create it using **promise**, but it still freeze the next statement.

```
  console.log("start");

  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    /* calculations */
  }).then((res) => console.log(res));

  console.log("end");
```

2. Then I used setTimeout function with time interval 0. LoL

```
  console.log("start");

  setTimeout(() => {
    /* calculations */
    console.log(res);
  }, 0);

  console.log("end");
```

Outputs:

```
start
end
"calculation result"
```

Both cases shows similar result, but using **promise** prevented to show `console.log("end")` before calculation finishes. Using **setTimeout** works as I wanted, and shows `console.log("end")` before calculation, so it was not freeze till calculation done.

I hope it was clear enough. Now for me using **setTimeout** is the best solution, but I would be happy to hear your ideas or any other method calculating concurrently without **setTimeout**.

Comment: No. JavaScript is single threaded. Use a web worker instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: AFAIK, promises and `setTimeout` do not automaticly enable parallel programming for JS.

Comment: If you run 2 async functions at the same time. The interpreter will jump between those 2 back and forth whenever one of them yields. So they never run at the same time. I think this may be called context switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The code you write under `new Promise(() => {..code here..})` is not asynchronous. The is a very common misconception that everything under the `Promise` block would run asynchronously.
   Instead, this JS API just let's get us a hook of some deferred task to be done once the promise is resolved. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises)

> **Promises are a comparatively new feature of the JavaScript language that allow you to defer further actions until after a previous action
> has completed, or respond to its failure. This is useful for setting
> up a sequence of async operations to work correctly.**

```
new Promise(() => {
    // whatever I write here is synchromous
    // like console.log, function call, setTimeout()/fetch()/async web apis
    // if there are some async tasks like fetch, setTimeout.
    // they can be async by themselves but their invocation is still sync
    // 
})
```

2. `setTimeout` is not the correct option either. Code under `setTimeout` would run when the event stack is empty and once it enters, it would block the main thread again.

The right approach to this would be to use Web Workers.